# PhpStorm and Ack for source code reading

Tags: ack, phpstorm

I need tools to browse large amounts of PHP source code and have heared PhpStorm
(the source code IDE from JetBrains) and Ack (The Perl5 module from beyondgrep.com)
are some of the best tools for the task at hand. Does PhpStorm already cover all of
the functionality provided by Ack, and if so where can I find those features in the
IDE, or is it better to install both of them and use them together? What's the
best approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PhpStorm, but ack is not a "browser".  It makes it easy to find code in large trees of code, but it's a command line tool, and there's nothing clickable about it.

Also, to be accurate, ack isn't a Perl module.